# Masking or changing certain text in URL

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, url

I'm using Composer with Toran Proxy hosted on a personal server to manage my package dependencies for Symfony2, today I encountered a problem, one of the URLs that Composer needs to download ends with **dependecy-injection.json**, every other URL downloads OK, but having those words it's something the proxy doesn't like, so it blocks it.

I have full access to the server, is there a way to mask o change that certain URL to make it look like another one and so "bypassing" the proxy?

This is the URL:

```
http://domainexample/toran/web/app.php/repo/packagist/p/symfony/dependency-injection.json
```

I'm using Apache2 as web server.

Comment: Can you not configuring proxy bypass lists instead?

Comment: The proxy guys will unlock it for a week, but then they will block it again because it's a personal server of mine, enterprise policies, you know... I'm looking for a long time solution here, because I'm sure I'll need it for more than a week. The funny thing is that everything works but that URL that has those words.